# Exposing iterator of generic vector

Tags: c++, generics, stdvector

I have a simple templated class with private generic `vector` and I wanted to expose `begin` and `end` iterators (in order to consume these outside that class in `std:accumulate`).

I am trying to achieve it like so:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class MyClass 
{
public:
    std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>::iterator begin() { return m_data.begin(); }
    std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>::iterator end() { return m_data.end(); }
    //...

private:
    std::vector<T> m_data;
    //...
};
```

But it seems that I am doing something wrong as it doesn't compiles and reports following:

```
C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'begin' 
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'begin' 
C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

That makes absolutely no sense for me, can you point me to how `begin` can be exposed?

Comment: You have to put typename before the dependent type. More info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords).

Comment: Solution was simply **typename** std::vector<T>::iterator begin() { return m_data.begin(); }